# jQuery doesn't work in an external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm a beginner of jQuery. I wanne write my jQuery in an external js file instead of in the head of html file, but it failed.

> index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="js/func.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="response">response is shown here</p>
<button id="bt_testJQ">jq test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

> func.js

```
document.write("<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>")`
`$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bt_testJQ").click(function () {
        $("#response").toggle();
    })
})
```

`

Comment: put this part `document.write` inside document the ready?or put you external script after body when the elements loaded

Comment: the question is why would you do this? Just include it in <script> tag before your func.js. If you REALLY need to do this in-script try this: `var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6tfjh1gs/1/

Comment: just wanna to avoid importing the jquery in every html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with putting the code in an external file, you'd have the same problem if it was inline.

`document.write`'s output is placed after the `<script></script>` element and parsed by the HTML parser when the script has finished running. Effectively, you are:

1. *setting up* jQuery to load
2. Trying to use jQuery
3. actually loading jQuery

You can't use jQuery before you load it.

The simple solution to this is to use two script elements in the HTML and load jQuery first.

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/func.js"></script><!-- with the document.write line removed -->
```

> just wanna to avoid importing the jquery in every html file.

This is best handled by either:

- Using a template system.
- Using a build system that combines the contents of all your scripts, including third party libraries, into a single file.

Answer (score 0):

A better way of doing this is have the jquery library called at the head and have your external js script at the last part of the body of your html

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="response">response is shown here</p>
<button id="bt_testJQ">jq test</button>
<script src="js/func.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems that “document.write” doesn't import the jquery lib in func.js. The jquery lib must be imported in index.html.

Comment: @Lynn from what i also learned you have to get the DOM elements loaded 1st before you can add event handler functionalities. It appears your original code is trying to run the script 1st but the elements where it will execute do not exist yet.

Comment: @Dren — No, it isn't. It tries to use a `ready` handler, which would avoid that problem.